# Translating exceptions for void Tasks with Task Parallel Library a la await

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exception, task-parallel-library

I need to translate an exception emanating from a `Task<T>` in the same manner that doing the following would for normal synchronous code:

```
try {
  client.Call();
} catch(FaultException ex) {
    if (ex.<Some check>)
        throw new Exception("translated");
}
```

However, I want to do this asynchronously, i.e., `Call` above is actually `Task CallAsync()`.

So in C# 5 my method would look like this:

```
async Task CallAndTranslate()
{
    try{
        await client.CallAsync();
    } catch(FaultException ex) {
        if (ex.FaultCode ...)
            throw new Exception("translated");
    }
}
```

But I'm using C# 4 for now.

So what can I do given that I want to trigger a Task but have the (TPL) Fault be translated and then expose the whole thing once again as a `Task<T>`?

- originally emanating from a WCF webservice but that's not important here

EDIT: A slightly more concrete way of saying it:

```
public class TranslatingExceptions
{
    public Task ApiAsync() // The inner layer exposes it exactly this way
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ throw new Exception( "Argument Null" );});
    }

    public Task WrapsApiAsync() // this layer needs to expose it exactly this way
    {
        // async preview pseudocode for what I need to do                            
        try {
            await ApiAsync(  );
        } catch (Exception exception){
            if( exception.Message == "Argument Null"  )
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Works()
    {
        var exception = Record.Exception( () => 
            WrapsApiAsync().Wait());
        Assert.IsType<ArgumentNullException>( exception.InnerException);
    }
}
```

How would you implement `WrapsApiAsync()` without needing C# 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so now that I'm entirely clear on what you're looking for, here's all you would need to do to build the equivalent in 4.0:

```
public class TranslatingExceptions
{
    public Task ApiAsync() // The inner layer exposes it exactly this way
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ throw new Exception( "Argument Null" );});
    }

    public Task WrapsApiAsync() // this layer needs to expose it exactly this way
    {
        // Grab the task that performs the "original" work
        Task apiAsyncTask = ApiAsync();

        // Hook a continuation to that task that will do the exception "translation"
        Task result = aspiAsync.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
        {
            // Check if the antecedent faulted, if so check what the exception's message was
            if ( antecedent.IsFaulted 
              && antecedent.Exception.InnerException.Message == "Argument Null" )
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        // Now we return the continuation Task from the wrapper method so that the caller of the wrapper method waits on that
        return result;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Works()
    {
        var exception = Record.Exception(() => 
                                         WrapsApiAsync().Wait());

        Assert.IsType<ArgumentNullException>(exception.InnerException);
    }
}
```

This should accomplish what you're looking for. One thing to note is that I use `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` when creating the continuation. This is because this work is small and tight and you don't want to incur the over head of waiting for a whole other thread having to be picked up from the thread pool by the scheduler just to do this check.

Comment: Thanks for the much appreciated response. Try as I might though, I cannot join the dots from your answer back to my problem. Very likely this is because my last CLR via C# read is a year and a half back and/or I'm misunderstanding 1 or more important principles. In my real problem, I'm passing a Task back through multiple layers in a chain. I'd really like for all my APIs to remain a clean single method returning Task thats easy to chain rather than have to use APM style throughout all the way down. I doubt that's what you're suggesting though!

Comment: It's fine that you're using Tasks internally, it's only at the WCF layer that you need to "switch" to the APM model because that's all the WCF stack currently understands and offers integration for in terms of getting the work off of one of it's I/O threads. I will whip together a sample for you.

Comment: Hmmm. I shouldnt have mentioned WCF as that's not the point (I'm consuming WCF at the innermost point only). But now that I have, I'll explain myself. I'm using [a `XXXTaskAsync` e tension on my WCF proxy](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/74e02263-da5e-487d-b57b-4f0c90342b7d) to enable yielding the work out as a `Task`. The issue is how, 3 layers out from that I wrap the Task in something (another Task that?) that can translate the exception should there be one.

Comment: In the edit to my question (which I failed to flag to you, mea culpa...) I hope I've got across the requirement which boils down to 'how would one most cleanly implement `WrapsApiAsync` without C# 5?'. In that context, I don't see how the APM is involved unless I expose an APM API down all the layers until someone needs to translate it. (I hope I'm not frustrating the heck out of you at this stage!)

Comment: Ah, I did miss that and I was thrown off by the WCF talk, sorry. Let me review your updated code sample and see if I can understand exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, sorry once again. I've tried a few different ideas but the fundamental issue I cant resolve is that I need to hand out a Task[CompletionSource] (that I can control the `Exception` of) - but I cant find a way to hook onto the completion/fault paths of the inner task (e.g., via ContinueWith) (though I can do a lovely placeholder implementation using `Task.Factory.StartNew` with a lambda doing a `.Wait()` in a try/catch block - but that just doesn't feel like the best answer possible...). (Almost) Makes me want to go back through Jon Skeet's C#5 async deconstruct to see how they do it!

Comment: Rethinking ... Creating a `TaskCompletionSource`, appending a `ContinueWith` to the inner task and from there feeding the (transformed) exception or result onto a the outer tcs.Task should just work and be tidy enough (thought I tried that in a learning test but hit a roadblock; can't recall why...).

Comment: Works perfectly (edited in a minor piece of AggregateException traversal logic)

Comment: ... But I have [a followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882211/translating-exceptions-for-taskt-with-task-parallel-library-a-la-await). (To be honest, this was my actual question in the first place - I had figured out the original approach but got blocked on extending it to `Task<T>`'s [returning a Result])