# Translating exceptions for Task<T> with Task Parallel Library a la await

Tags: .net, asynchronous, exception, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the dollowing C# 5 pseudocode:-

```
async Task<int> CallAndTranslate()
{
    try 
    {
        return await client.CallAsync();
    } catch(FaultException ex) {
        if (ex.FaultCode ...)
            throw new Exception("translated");
    }
}
```

[Given an arbitrary `Task` *which does not return a result*, translating exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852910/translating-exceptions-with-task-parallel-library-a-la-await/8853744#8853744) when backporting from C# 5 is easy [using the technique supplied by @Drew Marsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853744/11635)

This technique doesn't generalize trivially to `Task<T>` as any overload of `Task.ContinueWith` I can see returns a bald `Task`, not a `Task<T>`.

Is there a way to achieve this using the TPL APIs without having to resort to:

- wrapping it in another `Task<T>`
- causing the exception to go through the machinations of getting thrown and caught through the exception handling mechanisms
- ***ADDED After intial answer....*** should leave stack trace alone if exception is not to be translated

---

Here's my naive placeholder implementation:

```
public class TranslatingExceptions
{
    Task<int> ApiAsync()
    {
        return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew( () => { 
           throw new Exception( "Argument Null" ); } );
    }

    public Task<int> WrapsApiAsync() 
    {
        return ApiAsync().TranslateExceptions(x=>{
            if (x.Message == "Argument Null" )
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
        });
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Works()
    {
        var exception = Record.Exception( () =>
            WrapsApiAsync().Wait() );
        Assert.IsType<ArgumentNullException>( exception.InnerException );
    }
}
```

The following `Task<T>` extension implements my placeholder implementation:

```
static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> TranslateExceptions<T>( this Task<T> task, Action<Exception> translator )
    {
    // TODO REPLACE NAIVE IMPLEMENTATION HERE
        return Task<T>.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        {
            try
            {
                return task.Result;
            }
            catch ( AggregateException exception )
            {
                translator( exception.InnerException );
                throw;
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can imitate `await` in .NET 4.0 using iterators ( `yield` ), but it's not pretty.

Without a state machine, you're missing the whole point of `await` which is to return control to the caller until the work is complete and only then continue execution.

Um, maybe **I've** missed the point! If you just want to use a `ContinueWith<T>` it's just a slight tweak to the code from Drew Marsh:

```
public Task<int> ApiAsync() // The inner layer exposes it exactly this way
{
    return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        { throw new Exception( "Argument Null" ); } );
}

// this layer needs to expose it exactly this way
public Task<int> WrapsApiAsync()
{
    // Grab the task that performs the "original" work
    Task<int> apiAsyncTask = ApiAsync();

    // Hook a continuation to that task that will do the exception "translation"
    Task<int> result = apiAsyncTask.ContinueWith( antecedent =>
    {
        // Check if the antecedent faulted
        // If so check what the exception's message was
        if ( antecedent.IsFaulted )
        {
            if ( antecedent.Exception.InnerException.Message == "Argument Null" )
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            throw antecedent.Exception.InnerException;
        }

        return antecedent.Result;
    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously );

    // Now we return the continuation Task from the wrapper method
    // so that the caller of the wrapper method waits on that
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE: sample using TaskCompletionSource

```
public static Task<int> WrapsApiAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    Task<int> apiAsyncTask = ApiAsync();

    apiAsyncTask.ContinueWith( t =>
        {
            switch ( t.Status )
            {
                case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                    tcs.SetResult( task.Result );
                    break;

                case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                    tcs.SetCanceled();
                    break;

                case TaskStatus.Faulted:

                    if ( t.Exception.InnerException.Message == "Argument Null" )
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentNullException();
                        }
                        catch ( ArgumentNullException x )
                        {
                            tcs.SetException( x );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tcs.SetException( t.Exception.InnerException );
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    );

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately, as noted in the question, **Task**`.ContinueWith` does not return `Task<int>` is the problem here, hence asking the question (and casting unsurprisingly doesnt  work either). Perhaps, there's a ToTaskOf<T> convertor someone has? Either way, this wont pass in the provided testbed, sorry! (The bit I'm looking to replicate is not the state machine carry on, but the `Task<T>` juggling). And I cant remember the content of @Jon Skeet's excellent 'destructing async in C# 5' series from last year.

Comment: MSDN doesn't show all the overloads of `ContinueWith`, but there are certainly ones that return `Task<T>`. [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321561.aspx) is closest, but there is also one in .NET 4 RTM that takes a `Task<T>` as the antecedent.

Comment: Correct. It's not obvious, but you just return a result from the continuation method and the compiler will choose the appropriate overload resulting in the Task<T>.

Comment: Thanks both. Ah, sorry for originally doubting you (I missed the `return antedent.Result` bit)! Works perfectly as-is (Tried to add a `ContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` etc. but can't see any refinements possible.) Looks like I fell asleep while cycling through the 23 overloads of `ContinueWith` :D The only missing bit (as pointed out by @Drew Marsh in the previous case) is that the explicit re-`throw` will drop the original callstack - i.e., I'd ideally like to preserve `throw;` semantics (or VB filter ones :P). Will accept in due course assuming nobody comes up a no drop stacktrace impl.

Comment: @RubenBartelink No problem. I've added a code sample using `TaskCompletionSource` which doesn't re-throw the original exception.

Comment: Brilliant work - that's not perfect no matter how picky you get!